# Jsforce where clause having multiple conditions not working

Tags: javascript, query, jsforce, where

This below code results in  INVALID_FIELD: Test' AND ParentId = null AND EndDate > '2019-05-21' LIMIT 1 error.. How can I add more than one condition in where clasue?

```
const a = 2019-01-03
const b = 2019-02-03

connection.sobject('Campaign')
.find({
  Type: { $eq: 'Test' },
  ParentId: { $eq: null },
  EndDate: {
     $gt: a,
     $lt: b,
  }
})
.limit(1)
.then(data => {
  console.log(data);
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set your WHERE-clause as a string in JSForce:

```
connection.sobject('Campaign')
.where('Type = \'Test\' AND ParentID = NULL AND EndDate > ' + a + ' AND EndDate < ' + b)
.limit(1)
.then(data => {
  console.log(data);
})
```

See: https://jsforce.github.io/jsforce/doc/Query.html#where

Comment: Thank you so much! It worked!

Answer (score 0):

For anyone (like me) who comes along looking for a way to do this without having to build a string query, this can be achieved like so:

```
connection.sobject('Campaign')
.find({
  Type: { $eq: 'Test' },
  ParentId: { $eq: null },
  $and: [
     { EndDate: { $gt: a } },
     { EndDate: { $lt: b } },
  ]
})
.limit(1)
.then(data => {
  console.log(data);
});
```